# Can't receive push notification from Parse server and ionic app (ios)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, parse-server

I step into a problem that I don't even know what is the problem.

Trying with ios first.

I am making the push notification from parse server open source. I set up the parse server for push:

```
"push": {
      "ios":{
         "pfx": "/var/www..../Certificates.p12",
         "passphrase": "...",
         "bundleId": "com.xxxx.testPushNotification",
         "production": false
      }
   }
```

I am using this plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin. Here is my platform

```
Installed platforms:
  ios 4.3.1
Available platforms: 
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  android ~6.0.0
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  osx ~4.0.1
  webos ~3.7.0
```

and

```
cordova 6.4.0
```

and here is the code in app.js

```
$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
    pushNotification.register(
    tokenHandler,
    errorHandler,
    {
        "badge":"true",
        "sound":"true",
        "alert":"true",
        "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
    });
// result contains any message sent from the plugin call
function successHandler (result) {
    alert('result = ' + result);
}
// result contains any error description text returned from the plugin call
function errorHandler (error) {
    alert('error = ' + error);
}
function onNotificationAPN (event) {
  if ( event.alert )
  {
      navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
  }

  if ( event.sound )
  {
      var snd = new Media(event.sound);
      snd.play();
  }

  if ( event.badge )
  {
      pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
  }
}
  function tokenHandler (result) {
      // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
      // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
      alert('device token = ' + result);
  }
  // fired when push notification is received
  window.onNotification = function (e) {
      navigator.notification.alert('Notification received: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
  }  
  var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
  pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"channelName":"xxxx","ecb":"onNotification"});

  function successHandler(result) {
      console.log('registered###' + result.uri);
      // send uri to your notification server
  }
  function errorHandler(error) {
      console.log('error###' + error);
  }
```

basically I may manage the server side since I sent several of messages but they are not actually sent.

[please click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfd0n.png)

I managed to get the .p12 and .pem and the app id is matched between app and server side.

Where is my problem? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer myself, hope it helps

inside deviceReady()

```
if(window.ParsePushPlugin){
  ParsePushPlugin.getInstallationId(function(id) {
     // note that the javascript client has its own installation id,
     // which is different from the device installation id.
      alert("device installationId: " + id);
  }, function(e) {
      alert('error');
  });

  ParsePushPlugin.getSubscriptions(function(subscriptions) {
      alert(subscriptions);
  }, function(e) {
      alert('error');
  });

  ParsePushPlugin.subscribe('SampleChannel', function(msg) {
      alert('OK');
  }, function(e) {
      alert('error');
  });

  ParsePushPlugin.unsubscribe('SampleChannel', function(msg) {
      alert('OK');
  }, function(e) {
      alert('error');
  });
  ParsePushPlugin.on('receivePN', function(pn){
      alert('yo i got this push notification:' + JSON.stringify(pn));
  });
```

//inside config.xml

```
<preference name="ParseAppId" value="xxxxxx" />
<preference name="ParseServerUrl" value="http://xxxxx:1389/parse" />
<preference name="ParseGcmSenderId" value="xxxxxx" />
<preference name="ParseMultiNotifications" value="true" />
```

Plugin : https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin

Notice: set appId (app bundle) the same between server and app and make sure p12 and pem file in the root folder of your app.

Comment: Plugin : https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin does not work with ionic version 4